# Update Custom Datatable LWC Whenever Related ContentNote is Created/ Updated

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have created a custom datatable to display contentnotes related to an account record. I would like this table to update whenever a new contentnote related to the account record is created or updated. How can this be achieved?

I have tried using refreshApex and @track on the columns but neither technique is updating the data automatically- I am having to manually refresh it. From the research I've done, it seems that I will need to use Platform Events since I am using Apex Controller to query the data. But I would like to avoid that route if possible.

Controller

```
public with sharing class ContentNotesController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<NoteWrapper> getNotes(String accountId) {
        List<NoteWrapper> notes = new List<NoteWrapper>();

        List<ContentDocumentLink> documentLinks = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :accountId];

        for (ContentDocumentLink link : documentLinks) {
            ContentNote note = [SELECT Id, Title, Content, CreatedById, CreatedDate FROM ContentNote WHERE Id = :link.ContentDocumentId LIMIT 1];

            // Query the User object to get the user's name
            User createdByUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :note.CreatedById LIMIT 1];

            NoteWrapper noteWrapper = new NoteWrapper();
            noteWrapper.id = note.Id;
            noteWrapper.title = note.Title;
            noteWrapper.content = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(note.Content)).toString();
            noteWrapper.createdBy = createdByUser;
            noteWrapper.createdDate = note.CreatedDate;

            notes.add(noteWrapper);
        }

        return notes;
    }

    public class NoteWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String id { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String title { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String content { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public User createdBy { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

JS

```
// contentNotesLWC.js

import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getNotes from '@salesforce/apex/ContentNotesController.getNotes';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'title', type: 'text', sortable: true },
    { label: 'Content', fieldName: 'content', type: 'richtext', sortable: true },
    { label: 'Created By', fieldName: 'createdBy', type: 'text', sortable: true },
    { label: 'Created Date', fieldName: 'createdDate', type: 'text', sortable: true }
];

export default class ContentNotesLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; // Account Id passed from the parent component
    notes = [];
    columns = columns;

    @wire(getNotes, { accountId: '$recordId' })
    wiredNotes({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.notes = data.map(note => ({
                id: note.id,
                title: note.title,
                content: note.content,
                createdBy: note.createdBy.Name,
                createdDate: this.formatDate(note.createdDate),
                url: this.getNoteRecordUrl(note.id) // Generate the URL here
            }));
        } else if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    // Function to format date
    formatDate(dateString) {
        const options = {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: '2-digit',
            day: '2-digit',
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
        };
        return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(new Date(dateString));
    }

    // Function to generate the URL for the note record
    getNoteRecordUrl(noteId) {
        return `/${noteId}`;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- contentNotesLWC.html -->

<template>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
            <!-- Add the Notes icon or adjust as needed -->
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:note" size="small" class="header-icon"></lightning-icon>
            <h2 class="header-title">Notes</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="datatable-container">
            <div class="datatable-header">
                <div class="datatable-cell">
                    <strong>Subject</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="datatable-cell datatable-cell-content">
                    <strong>Content</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="datatable-cell">
                    <strong>Created By</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="datatable-cell">
                    <strong>Created Date/Time</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="datatable-body">
                <template for:each={notes} for:item="note">
                    <div key={note.id} class="datatable-row">
                        <div class="datatable-cell">
                            <a href={note.url}>{note.title}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="datatable-cell datatable-cell-content">
                            <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={note.content}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                        </div>
                        <div class="datatable-cell">{note.createdBy}</div>
                        <div class="datatable-cell">{note.createdDate}</div>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

CSS

```
/* contentNotesLWC.css */

.content {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.datatable-container {
    max-height: 300px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add a border for better appearance */
}

.datatable-header {
    display: flex;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #f2f2f2; /* Light gray background color */
}

.datatable-cell:first-child {
    flex: 1; /* Adjust the width of the first column as needed */
}

.datatable-body {
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling for the body */
}

.datatable-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; /* Light gray border between rows */
}

.datatable-cell {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0.5rem; /* Add padding to the cells for better appearance */
}

.datatable-cell-content {
    flex: 3; /* Set the width to 50% */
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.header-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.header-icon {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What part of it isn't working? Please edit your question with more information about where you're stuck or this question is likely to be closed

Comment: It is not so much that they are complicated, but rather the limitations. For example, ContentNotes are not triggerable and also it does not seem possible to render Rich Text fields with them. I was looking into that route originally, but due to the limitations, I avoided it